# POST method in WCF SOAP service

Tags: wcf, post, soap, methods, service

I know how to create a REST service using POST (using [WebInvoke]). Is there any way to make a POST method in SOAP service? Is it viable/feasible? Do anyone have any reference which could give me a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about what you mean.

General soap service all uses post method.

You could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-define-a-wcf-service-contract  to learn how to create a soap service using wcf.